# Position element on page based on its height and width

Tags: jquery, css

I have built a drop-down menu here http://dev.driz.co.uk/jsonmenu/ that uses JSON to dynamically build the menus. The reason for doing this insead of putting the HTML in the page itself is for performance (only load what you need) and so that I can position the menu outside of the table.

I have begun implementing a way to position the menu based on its height and proximity to the window (browser window NOT the scrollable container). The problem is that when the height of the menu is bigger than the space below the link and viewport then it should move the menu above and vice-versa. Parts of it are working just not quite correctly.

NOTE: The reason the positioning is done after the HTML is inserted rather than in a callback if user moves the window etc is because the menu is removed if the user scrolls or anything like that so it would be pointless to do it then.

Code as requested:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('a.buildMenu').click(function (event) {

                // Prevent normal behaviour
                event.preventDefault();

                // Stops it bubbling to the document
                event.stopPropagation();

                var link = $(this);

                // If the menu already exists remove it and exit the request
                if($(document).find('div#' + $(link).data('id')).length){
                    $('.buildMenu').removeClass('selected');
                    $('.menu').remove();
                    return false;
                }

                // Remove any other menus from the DOM
                $('.buildMenu').removeClass('selected');
                $('.menu').remove();

                // Get the position of the link
                var offset = link.offset();
                var top = offset.top;
                var left = offset.left; 
                var bottom = top + link.height();
                var right = $(window).width() - link.width();

                top = top + link.height();

                bottom = bottom + link.height();

                // Append the menu to the DOM in position
                var menuInstance = $('<div class="menu loading">loading...</div>').appendTo('body').css({'position':'absolute','top':top,'left':left});

                // Add the instance id
                $(menuInstance).attr('id', $(link).data('id'));

                // Add class of selected to clicked link
                $(this).addClass('selected');

                // Request JSON data        
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'menu.json',
                    timeout: 5000,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function (data) {

                        // Build the menu
                        var ul = $("<ul/>").attr("id", data.menu.id).addClass(data.menu.class);

                        // For each menu item
                        $.each(data.menu.content.menuitem, function () {
                            var li = $("<li/>").appendTo(ul).addClass(this.liClass);
                            var anchor = $("<a/>").appendTo(li).attr("href", this.href).attr("title", this.title);
                            var span = $("<span/>").appendTo(anchor).addClass(this.icon).html(this.text)
                        });

                        // Remove the loading class and insert menu into instance
                        $(menuInstance).removeClass('loading').html(ul);

                        // If the menu is taller than the bottom space
                        if(menuInstance.height() > bottom) {
                            menuInstance.css({'top':'auto','bottom':bottom,'left':left});
                        }
                        // If the menu is taller than the top space
                        else if(menuInstance.height() > top) {
                            menuInstance.css({'top':top,'left':left});
                        }
                        // Default position...
                        else {
                            menuInstance.css({'top':top,'left':left});
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                });

            });

            // Remove menu from DOM if anything except the menu is clicked
            $(document).bind('click', function (event) {
                var clicked = $(event.target);
                if (!clicked.parents().hasClass('menu')) {
                    $('.buildMenu').removeClass('selected');
                    $('.menu').remove();
                }
            });

            // Remove menu if user scrolls panel
            $(window).bind('resize', function() {   
                $('.buildMenu').removeClass('selected');
                $('.menu').remove();
            });

            $('div').bind('scroll', function() {    
                $('.buildMenu').removeClass('selected');
                $('.menu').remove();
            });

        });
```

Here is a screenshot of the issue (the code should make that menu appear above the link because its height is bigger than the offset space below the link)

[image]

Comment: It is better if you copy your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with Line 71-74.

```
// If the menu is taller than the bottom space
if(menuInstance.height() > bottom) {
      menuInstance.css({'top':'auto','bottom':bottom,'left':left});
}
```

`bottom` is being calculated as the distance from the top of the window to bottom of the menu link ... and you're saying "if the menu height is bigger than that".

I think what you're wanting to check is the if the menu height is bigger than the distance from the bottom of the menu link to the bottom of the window. So...

```
    if(menuInstance.height() > ($(window).height() - bottom) )
```

This should take the distance from the bottom of the link to the bottom of the window and compare that to the height of the menu.

Then you need to correct how you're position `menuInstance`.

```
    'bottom': ($(window).height() - top) + link.height()
```

Here's the full code...

```
    // If the menu is taller than the bottom space
    if (menuInstance.height() > ($(window).height() - bottom)) {
        menuInstance.css({
            'top': 'auto',
            'bottom': ($(window).height() - top) + link.height(),
            'left': left
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm not interested in the position of container div. As the menus can and should be able to sit outside of it. It's more of a case of whether the menu can fit on the screen below the link or does it need to be moved. So it should be relevant to the window NOT the container.

Comment: Though, I've got to say it seems strange that you're using a AJAX menu for "performance" and "positioning outside the window" ... being the same menu, every time the link is clicked it has to reload the same menu. Is that really a performance benefit? (And isn't the point of this request so you can keep the menu "inside" the table?

Comment: Oh. I see what you're saying now.

Comment: No I'm not trying to keep the menu inside the table at all! And it's only loading the same menu because it's a demo.

Comment: Same principle applies. Just add the distance outside the container `div` to both sides of the equation.

Comment: Modified the answer. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you see my edited OP you will see a screenshot of the issue. Basically the menu is bigger than the space below that linke `bottom` var in this case and so the menu should be positioned above the link rather than below it.

Comment: Did you see my modified answer? `if(menuInstance.height() > ($(window).height() - bottom) )`

Comment: Output your values via `console.log(/*value here*/)` and see if they're what you're expecting. Perhaps something else is messed up. That code seems to function for me.

Comment: The problem is that even though we get the menu height after inserting the HTML content into it, it is still getting the height before the content hence why its height is smaller... Is their a callback for the success of inserting the HTML? Note this is different to the success callback as it's inside that!

Comment: So the height of `menuInstance` is coming back as 0?

Comment: No it's coming back as what it is before the content is entered into the menu even though I get the height AFTER the call to insert the content but it clearly happens simultaneously so doesn't measure after the change like I wanted it to.

Comment: I duplicated your code into a jsfiddle and a console.log() tells me that it is getting calculated correctly, but your position of the menu is off. I updated the answer to what works for my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/9ZNn9/